# Como hacer figuras irregulares

Tags: css

Lo que quiero realizar es un triangulo isósceles con las puntas recortadas o chatas en este caso va a tener 6 puntas como un hexágono, pero desconozco como se puede realizar esto desde CSS.

He intentado algo como esto:

```css
.triangulo_mascara{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 3.4em;
  height: 4em;
  font-size: 35px; /*Con esto controlo el tamaño*/
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.triangulo{
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent crimson;
  border-width: 0 2em 5em 2em;
  margin: -1em 0 0 -.3em;
}

.demo_sin_mascara{
  margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
  border: solid ;
  overflow: initial; 
}

.demo_sin_mascara .triangulo{
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
Así voy
<div class="triangulo_mascara">
  <span class="triangulo"></span>
</div>
Como hice esta versión del triangulo
<div class="triangulo_mascara demo_sin_mascara">
  <span class="triangulo"></span>
</div>
```

Aunque las puntas de abajo deberían ser chatas como un hexágono en diagonal.

Comment: Hola Jorge, debes añadir algo más de información: ¿qué has investigado sobre esto? ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿con qué problemas/dificultades te estás encontrando? ¿cuál es tu código HTML? También sería ideal que añadieses una imagen con lo que quieres. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: ¿Te planteas usar algo como SVG o canvas para hacer esto en lugar de usar CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres que el hexágono sea editable por dentro te sugiero lo hagas con **`clip-path`**. Se usa así:

```
.triangulo{
  clip-path: polygon(x1 y2, x2 y2, x3 y3, x4 y4, x5 y5, xN yN);
}
```

Mira:

```css
.forma{
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.triangulo{
  clip-path: polygon(42% 0%, 58% 0%, 100% 88%, 92% 100%, 8% 100%, 0% 88%)
}
```

```html
<div class="forma triangulo"></div>
```

---

Ahora lo siguiente  no es necesario, pero simplifica un poco la edición de todo, eres libre de usar o no esta opción:

```css
.forma{
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.triangulo{
  /*Solo debes editar esta linea y ya*/
  --anchura_esquina: 20px;
  /*Lo que viene no se toca*/
  --x: calc(var(--anchura_esquina) / 0.6);
  --xy1: calc(50% - var(--anchura_esquina));
  --xy2: calc(50% + var(--anchura_esquina));
  --xy3: calc(100% - var(--x));
  --xy4: calc(100% - var(--x));
  --xy5: calc(0% + var(--x));
  --xy6: calc(100% - var(--x));
  clip-path: 
    polygon( 
      var(--xy1) 0,
      var(--xy2) 0,
      100% var(--xy3), 
      var(--xy4) 100%,
      var(--xy5) 100%,
      0 var(--xy6) 
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="forma triangulo"></div>
```

---

### Actualización

Esta opción de enmascaramiento, no tiene la posibilidad de añadir sombras normales o bordes, aunque puedes simularlas añadiendole un padre contenedor y usar las sombras generadas por filtros:

```css
.forma{
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: white;
}

.triangulo{
  clip-path: polygon(42% 0%, 58% 0%, 100% 88%, 92% 100%, 8% 100%, 0% 88%)
}

.contenedor_forma{
  display: inline-block;
  filter: 
    drop-shadow(2px 0 0 red) 
    drop-shadow(0 2px 0 red) 
    drop-shadow(-1px 0 0 red) 
    drop-shadow(0 -1px 0 red)
    drop-shadow(3px 0 0 blue) 
    drop-shadow(0 3px 0 blue) 
    drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 blue) 
    drop-shadow(0 -2px 0 blue) 
    drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor_forma">
 <div class="forma triangulo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: desconocía esa propiedad y me sirve de mucho, ahora el problema lo tengo con los bordes ya que al momento de poner bordes no se pintan el algunos lados de la figura, lo que se me ocurre es hacer un suplicado de la figura y ponerla de fondo o habrá alguna otra manera mas sencilla de realizarlo?

Comment: No se pueden añadir bordes a una figura recortada, pero si que puedes envolverla en otra y añadirle sobra lateral a los lados, ya actualizo mi respuesta para mostrarte como.

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudaste muchisimo con esa respuesta, te lo agradesco